# How to get each status of a matrix job?

Tags: github-actions

I would like to build a GitHub Actions workflow with two jobs.

The first "deploy" job, uses a matrix strategy to deploy on different environments. The second "notification" job should run afterwards for each env and access the state of the "deploy" job. Do you have any guidance on how to achieve this?

Pseudocode would look something like this:

```yaml
jobs:

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash
        working-directory: ./infrastructure
    strategy:
      max-parallel: 3
      matrix:
        stage: [ dev, int, prd ]
      fail-fast: true
    ... 

  notification:
    needs: deploy
    if: always()
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # somehow access ${{ job.deploy.status }} for each matrix stage
```

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/17245?

Comment: No, thank you very much for pointing this out!